# Як перекласти "отрисовка", "drawing"

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова

Треба перекласти вираз "*Отрисовка* математической капчи". Прямого перекладу немає, намагалась винайти щось відповідне. Зазвичай словом "отрисовка" послуговуються дизайнери, що праюють в графічних редакторах. За поясненнями [форумчан](https://photoshop-master.ru/forum/index.php/topic/25038-chto-znachit-otrisovka/),

> Отрисовка в основном значении слова - это обтравка (обводка) контуров
>   рисунка или фотографии векторными инструментами (либо в векторном
>   редакторе). Суть отрисовки – это превращение маленькой картинки в
>   большую, часто делается для улучшения качества исходника. То есть
>   проще говоря, обрисовываете с помощью пера, а затем раскрашиваете
>   (кисть либо заливки).

Але стосовно створення капчі таке визначення мало допомагає, тому що використання різних фарб - лише допоміжний фактор. Більш важливим є зміна розміру і  кута нахилу цифр, додавання шумних ефектів, динамічні викривлення тощо.
Як варіанти, в різних джерелах пропонується *прокреслення, вимальовка, рисування*, та їх значення не зовсім відповідає потрібному.
Чи є в українському спеціальному лексиконі усталена назва такого процесу? Чи яке слово може точніше передати суть дії?

Comment: мені здається, що краще подумати як це звучало англійською і перекладати з англійської і не прив'язуватись до визначень утворених в результаті перекладу англомовних термінів на російську.

Answer (score 3):

Можна ще перекладати як "промальовка". Це слово вживають в  [свіжому шкільному підручнику по образотворчому мистецтву](https://books.google.cz/books?hl=uk&id=uV_uvLjGrr4C&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#v=snippet&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&f=false) в контексті "ретельна промальовка деталей".

Comment: -1, такий переклад може змінити розуміння терміну. Мета капчі - ускладнити доступ(для ботів), тому малюнок повинен сприйматися людиною та не поддаватися "простим" алгоритмам розпізнавання. Ретельна промальовка(я не знайшов цього слова у словнику, і воно доступне мені тільки у сенсі уточнення чогось графічного) протипоказана. По суті відповідь вже написав [Sasha в коментарі](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-drawing#comment6979_4232).

Comment: @Kvaz1r, а мені здається, _промальовка_ підійшла б. Тобто з логічної точки зору це слово непотрібне (як, власне, й _отрисовка_ в оригіналі) — але інтуїтивно, мені здається, читач перекладу зрозумів би про що мова. Слово, хоч і не словникове, але звучить природно й на практиці вживається. Тому поставив плюса. Тим більше, що передивлятися це питання й відповіді на нього можуть не лише ті, кому це потрібно в контексті капчі, а й ті, хто шукають відповідники для рос. _отрисовка_ в інших контекстах. А свої коментарі я перетворив на [окрему відповідь](/a/4990).

Comment: @Sasha, не заперечую, ця відповідь має право на існування та може бути покрашена. Власне мій коментар спрямований в першу чергу на це. Якщо було б обгрунтування вибору слова стосовно наведенного контекста або окремо відзначена б застосовність слова не до конкретного випадку, а до слова _отрисовка_ в принципі - .інша справа.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Оскільки мої коментарі знайшли прихильників, перетворю їх на відповідь.</sub>

Я вважаю, що слово *отрисовка* в цьому контексті не несе якогось специфічного змісту — це просто малювання/рисування капчі (чесно кажучи, різницю між малюванням і рисуванням я не до кінця розумію, але я маю на увазі, що рос. слово *отрисовка* тут не позначає нічого специфічного порівняно із загальнішим рос. словом *рисование*). Я вважаю, що *отрисовка* тут вжито просто заради різноманітності/солідності, а не з метою вточнення.

І означення з форуму, що Ви наводите, здаться, цього випадку не стосується (якби воно стосувалося, то це, мабуть, уже була б задача розпізнавання, а не малювання/рисування/генерації).

Відповідно:

- у цьому випадку цілком підходять загальні слова на зразок **малювання/рисування** (яке більше — мені важко сказати, бо я не до кінця розумію різницю);
- також у разі автоматичного створення чогось часто застосовують слово **<s>[генерація](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18079&page=610)</s> [генерування](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18080&page=610)**, наприклад, *генерування математичної капчі в графічному вигляді*;
- ну й чисто теоретично можна обійти використання вживаного, але запозиченого слова *генерування* використанням його синонімів: **створення/продукування/формування**.

Answer (score 0):

Якщо звернутись до мови *оригіналу*, то це буде щось на кшталт *render mathematical captcha* або ж *renering of mathematical capthca*. Можна звернутись до [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=rendering&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) де маємо

> **rendering** = відтворення (зображення), візуалізація, формування зображення, рендеринг

Отже,

- відтворення капчі
- візуалізація капчі
- формування зображення капчі
- рендеринг капчі

Answer (score 0):

Читаємо англійський словник

> When you [draw](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draw), or when you draw something, you use a pencil or pen to produce a picture, pattern, or diagram.

Коли ви draw чи коли ви draw щось, то ви використовуєте олівець чи ручку, щоб виробити картину, закономірність чи діаграму.

> A [drawing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drawing) is a picture made with a pencil or pen.

**drawing** - це картина створена за допомогою олівця чи ручки.

А тепер наші

> [МАЛЮВА́ТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - Зображувати кого-, що-небудь на площині олівцем, пером,
> фарбами і т. ін.
>
> [МАЛЮ́НОК](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) - Зображення предмета на площині, зроблене олівцем, пером, фарбами і т.
> ін.
>
> [**МАЛЮВА́ННЯ**](http://%D0%A2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5,%20%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%CC%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) - Те саме, що малю́нок

А тепер щодо CAPTCHA

> Captcha is an abbreviation for 'completely automated public Turing
> test to tell computers and humans apart'.

**Цілком автоматична прилюдна перевірка Тюрінга, щоб відрізнити комп'ютерів від людей.**

Якщо коротко, то це перевірка Тюрінга.

Повертаємося до "Треба перекласти вираз "Отрисовка математической капчи".".

На основі контрольного слова перевірка можна описати таким чином:

Створюємо картинку з заплутаним виглядом (зображенням) чисел (або з заплутаним виглядом математичних дій, якщо на картинці є математичні дії) для **CAPTCHA** (для цілком автоматичної прилюдної перевірки ....).

Властивостями заплутування є:

- зміна розміру і кута нахилу цифр;
- ...

Або методи заплутування:

- накладання ліній, або інших фігур;
- розмивання;
- заплутування кольорами;
- ...